# Postgres: huge table with (delayed) read and write access

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, bigdata

I have a huge table (currently ~3mil rows, expected to increase by a factor of 1000) with lots of inserts every second. The table is never updated.

Now I have to run queries on that table which are pretty slow (as expected). These queries do not have to be 100% accurate, it is ok if the result is a day old (but not older).

There is currently two indexes on two single integer columns and I would have to add two more indexes (integer and timestamp columns) to speed up my queries.

The ideas I had so far:

1. Add the two missing indexes to the table
2. No indexes on the huge table at all and copy the content (as a daily task) to a second table (just the important rows) then create the indexes on the second table and run the queries on that table?
3. Partitioning the huge table
4. Master/Slave setup (writing to the master and reading from the slaves).

What option is the best in terms of performance? Do you have any other suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Here is the table (I have marked the foreign keys and prettified the query a bit):

```
CREATE TABLE client_log
(
   id                 serial          NOT NULL,
   logid              integer         NOT NULL,
   client_id          integer         NOT NULL,  (FOREIGN KEY)
   client_version     varchar(16),
   sessionid          varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
   created            timestamptz     NOT NULL,
   filename           varchar(256),
   funcname           varchar(256),
   linenum            integer,
   comment            text,
   domain             varchar(128),
   code               integer,
   latitude           float8,
   longitude          float8,
   created_on_server  timestamptz     NOT NULL,
   message_id         integer,                   (FOREIGN KEY)
   app_id             integer         NOT NULL,  (FOREIGN KEY)
   result             integer
);

CREATE INDEX client_log_code_idx ON client_log USING btree (code);
CREATE INDEX client_log_created_idx ON client_log USING btree (created);
CREATE INDEX clients_clientlog_app_id ON client_log USING btree (app_id);
CREATE INDEX clients_clientlog_client_id ON client_log USING btree (client_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX clients_clientlog_logid_client_id_key ON client_log USING btree (logid, client_id);
CREATE INDEX clients_clientlog_message_id ON client_log USING btree (message_id);
```

And an example query:

```
SELECT 
    client_log.comment, 
    COUNT(client_log.comment) AS count 
FROM 
    client_log
WHERE 
    client_log.app_id = 33 AND
    client_log.code = 3 AND 
    client_log.client_id IN (SELECT client.id FROM client WHERE 
        client.app_id = 33 AND 
        client."replaced_id" IS NULL)
GROUP BY client_log.comment ORDER BY count DESC;
```

*client_log_code_idx* is the index needed for the query above. There is other queries needing the *client_log_created_idx* index.

And the query plan:

```
Sort  (cost=2844.72..2844.75 rows=11 width=242) (actual time=4684.113..4684.180 rows=70 loops=1)
  Sort Key: (count(client_log.comment))
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 32kB
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2844.42..2844.53 rows=11 width=242) (actual time=4683.830..4683.907 rows=70 loops=1)
        ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1358.52..2844.32 rows=20 width=242) (actual time=303.515..4681.211 rows=1202 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (client_log.client_id = client.id)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on client_log  (cost=1108.02..2592.57 rows=387 width=246) (actual time=113.599..4607.568 rows=6962 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: ((app_id = 33) AND (code = 3))
                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=1108.02..1108.02 rows=387 width=0) (actual time=104.955..104.955 rows=0 loops=1)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on clients_clientlog_app_id  (cost=0.00..469.96 rows=25271 width=0) (actual time=58.315..58.315 rows=40662 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (app_id = 33)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on client_log_code_idx  (cost=0.00..637.61 rows=34291 width=0) (actual time=45.093..45.093 rows=36310 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (code = 3)
              ->  Hash  (cost=248.06..248.06 rows=196 width=4) (actual time=61.069..61.069 rows=105 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4kB
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on client  (cost=10.95..248.06 rows=196 width=4) (actual time=27.843..60.867 rows=105 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (app_id = 33)
                          Filter: (replaced_id IS NULL)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 271
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on clients_client_app_id  (cost=0.00..10.90 rows=349 width=0) (actual time=15.144..15.144 rows=380 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (app_id = 33)
Total runtime: 4684.843 ms
```

Comment: This cannot be answered without more information. What does the query look like? What is the execution plan for the query (you might want to read this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions ). But in general I'd start with trying different indexes (with your rate of insertion make sure you drop all unneeded indexes) then maybe try partitioning.

Comment: Your `id  serial` is probably intended as a primary key : try -->> `id (big)serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Thats a good point. I have changed it with: `ALTER TABLE client_log DROP COLUMN id;` `ALTER TABLE client_log ADD COLUMN id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;` (the _id_ was not used anywhere else).

Answer (score 5):

In general, in a system where time related data is constantly being inserted into the database, I'd recommend [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) according to time.

This is not just because it might improve query times, but because otherwise it makes managing the data difficult. However big your hardware is, it will have a limit to its capacity, so you will eventually have to start removing rows that are older than a certain date. The rate at which you remove the rows will have to be equal to the rate they are going in.

If you just have one big table, and you remove old rows using DELETE, you will leave a lot of dead tuples that need to be vacuumed out. The autovacuum will be running constantly, using up valuable disk IO.

On the other hand, if you partition according to time, then removing out of date data is as easy as dropping the relevant child table.

In terms of indexes - the indexes are not inherited, so you can save on creating the indexes until after the partition is loaded. You could have a partition size of 1 day in your use case. This means the indexes do not need to be constantly updated as data is being inserted. It will be more practical to have additional indexes as needed to make your queries perform.

Your sample query does not filter on the 'created' time field, but you say other queries do. If you partition by time, and are careful about how you construct your queries, constraint exclusion will kick in and it will only include the specific partitions that are relevant to the query.

Answer (score 1):

Except for partitioning I would consider splitting the table into many tables, aka Sharding.

I don't have the full picture of your domain but these are some suggestions:

Each client get their own table in their own schema (or a set of clients share a schema depending on how many clients you have and how many new clients you expect to get).

```
create table client1.log(id, logid,.., code, app_id);
create table client2.log(id, logid,.., code, app_id);
```

Splitting the table like this should also reduce the contention on inserts.

The table can be split even more. Within each client-schema you can also split the table per "code" or "app_id" *or something else that makes sense for you*. This might be overdoing it but it is easy to implement if the number of "code" and/or "app_id" values do not change often.
Do keep the code/app_id columns even in the new smaller tables but do put a constraint on the column so that no other type of log record can be inserted. The constraint will also help the optimiser when searching, see this example:

```
create schema client1;
set search_path = 'client1';

create table error_log(id serial, code text check(code ='error'));
create table warning_log(id serial, code text check(code ='warning'));
create table message_log(id serial, code text check(code ='message'));
```

To get the full picture (all rows) of a client you can use a view on top of all tables:

```
create view client_log as
select * from error_log
union all
select * from warning_log
union all
select * from message_log;
```

The check constraints should allow the optimiser to only search the table where the "code" can exist.

```
explain
select * from client_log where code = 'error';
-- Output
Append  (cost=0.00..25.38 rows=6 width=36)
  ->  Seq Scan on error_log  (cost=0.00..25.38 rows=6 width=36)
        Filter: (code = 'error'::text)
```